# How to sent data Data to the server by angular 2

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 How do i send data to the server according to the form model. In some case I might add more row by clicking addMore Button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgA12.png)

Answer (score 4):

First you need to import the `HttpModule`, and if you're going to send the json_encoded data, you need to import `JsonpModule`, as well. You can import both modules from `@angular/http` and add it to your `app.module.ts` file as the imports inside your `@NgModule`

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Next step is to make a service which will handle the Http Requests. You will need to import an `Observable` object and `map` method from `rxjs` package to work with the response. Also, you need to import the Http, Response, Headers and RequestOptions objects if you want to post data with POST HTTP Request (all object are in `@angular/http`. In service, you set up the function that you can access from your component and use it to send the data to server and catch the response that you can subscribe to.

**http.service.ts:**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    private _url: string = "http://example.com"; // Url which handles JSON encoded data 

    constructor(private _http: Http) {} // Injecting the Http Service

    sendData(data): Observable<Object> {

        let encoded_data = JSON.stringify({ data });
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.post(encoded_data, this._url, options).map(
            (res: Response) => res.json() || {}
        );

}
```

In component you need to import the service and use the method you've just created. You can also subscribe to this method to get the response.

**example.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from 'http.service';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _httpService: HttpService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    sendDataToServer(dataFromForm) {

        this._httpService.sendData(dataFromForm).subscribe(

            response => console.log(response), // success
            error => console.log(error),       // error
            () => console.log('completed')     // complete

    }

}
```

More information can be found here [HTTP Client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)

Comment: how do I send as an array [ Like:  If I have 20 more or more data ].

Comment: well.. you can make event trigger on your form tag `(submit)="sendDataToServer(yourForm.value)"` .. then it's get stringified and send to server. But, .. the server needs to be able to handle the stringified data... otherwise it would not work

Comment: @Ripon actually, now when I'm reading this once agan, you can stringify your array with json_encode and then on the server side you'll just need to json_parse it and use it as an array,.. as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

Use the Http class, which in its most basic form could be utilized something like:

```
export class EndPointService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

     public postData(url: string, data: any): Response {
        return this._http.post(url, data).map((res: Response) => {
            return res.json();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I send as an array [Like:  If I have 20 more rows ].

Comment: The array will be stringified before its sent across the wire. `any` handles any type - although its not type safe.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Note I omitted options, but they may be required - CORS and such