# Converting AngularJS $http request to Angular2 POST

Tags: angularjs, http, angular, post, request

I have the following Angular 1.5 $http request:

```
 this.$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "example.com",
    data: {
        "action" : "myAction"
    },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function(obj) {...}
});
```

And I'm trying to rewrite it to Angular2, but I don't know how the "data" and "transformRequest" properties translate. So far I have:

```
let options = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        headers: myHeader
});
this.http.post(
        'example.com',
        options
);
```

How can I add the Angular2 equivalent of "data" and "transformRequest"?

Comment: for "data" see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735866/how-to-sent-data-data-to-the-server-by-angular-2

Comment: for transformRequest see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905043/http-transform-request-in-angular-2